# Ajax call returns string for Highcharts series but result is wrong (parsing error?)

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, highcharts

I'm developing a Java Spring-Hibernate application that uses Highcharts. I've got a JavaScript function that, when called, it makes an Ajax call to get the chart data (series) and creates the chart with it:

```
<!-- Stacked bar chart -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Function that plots the highcharts chart
            function plot(park) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "MainView/report/datagaps/" + park,
                    dataType: "text",
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert('Error while requesting datagaps for ' + park + ' : ' + error);
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#chart" + park).highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: 'column'
                            },
                            series: result
                        });
                    }
                });
            }//END_FUNCTION
        </script>
```

I've removed most of the plot options code, so you see the most relevant code above. There is a model method that deals with this request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/datagaps/{parkName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String datagaps(@PathVariable String parkName, Map model, HttpSession session) {
        LOGGER.debug("Successfully called datagaps for '" + parkName + "'");
        LOGGER.debug((String) session.getAttribute("chartData"+parkName));
        return (String) session.getAttribute("chartData"+parkName);
    }//END_METHOD
```

The method is quite simple: a session string variable is returned, which is the one that should be used in `series: result`.
The thing is that this generates an unexpected result:
[image]

However, if I set a model variable `session.setAttribute("chartData" + park, rrdao.getParkData().get(park));` before loading the form and I use it instead of the result like `series: ${chartDataAA}`, it works:

[image]

This is quite weird, since the data used is exactly the same: both ajax call and model variable come from the same place, and they are logged before beign send, which allows me to be sure data is good. This data has a format like `[{name:'AA01', data: [[1412114400000,0],[1412200800000,0],[1412287200000,0],[1412373600000,0],[1412460000000,0],[1412546400000,0],[1412632800000,0]}]`
I bet is some kind of string parsing problem when it is returned from the ajax call, perhaps due to the single quotations, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe it is misspelling, but your single serie which you have as missing bracket in data array. It should be: [{name:'AA01', data: [[1412114400000,0],[1412200800000,0],[1412287200000,0],[1412373600000,0],[1412460000000,0],[1412546400000,0],[1412632800000,0]] }]

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if it was (also) a mispelling, but at least I had to apply some changes to `result` string. I replaced single quotacions by doubles and I added them as well in both name and data, so the final string ended like: `[{"name":"AA01", "data": [[1412114400000,0],[1412200800000,0],[1412287200000,0],[1412373600000,0],[141246‌​0000000,0],[1412546400000,0],[1412632800000,0]] }]` . Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: Right now, looks like fine, so works properly?

Comment: Yes, it does. Sorry I wasn't clear about that on my last answer

Comment: Sounds great, I added my comment as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is misspelling, but your single serie which you have as missing bracket in data array. It should be: `[{name:'AA01', data: [[1412114400000,0],[1412200800000,0],[1412287200000,0],[1412373600000,0],[141246‌​0000000,0],[1412546400000,0],[1412632800000,0]] }]`

Comment: Well, I think it still needs the quotations on name and data, as I stated on one of my replies. I'll give you the correct answer but please edit it to avoid other people making mistakes. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Change: `dataType: "text"` to `dataType: "json"`

Then in the controller if you use jackson json just return a List